# how attr_accessor works in ActiveResource rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How does `attr_accessor` works in `ActiveResource`?

```
class User < ActiveResource::Base
 attr_accessor :name
end
```

How its different from `attr_accessor` in `ActiveRecor`d?

Comment: Why do you think they are different?

Answer (score 2):

`attr_accessor` is built into Ruby, not rails. You may be confusing it with `attr_accessible`, which is part of `ActiveRecord`. Here's the difference:

#### attr_accessor

Take a class:

```
class Dog
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name

  def initialize(first_name, last_name)
    self.first_name = first_name
    self.last_name = last_name
  end
end
```

`attr_accessor` creates a property and creates methods that allow it to be readable and writeable. Therefore, the above class would allow you to do this:

```
my_dog = Dog.new('Rex', 'Thomas')
puts my_dog.first_name     #=> "Rex"

my_dog.first_name = "Baxter"
puts my_dog.first_name     #=> "Baxter"
```

It creates two methods, one for setting the value and one for reading it. If you only want to read *or* write, then you can use `attr_reader` and `attr_writer` respectively.

#### attr_accessible

This is an ActiveRecord specific thing that looks similar to `attr_accessor`. However, it behaves very differently. It specifies which fields are allowed to be mass-assigned. For example:

```
class User
  attr_accessible :name, :email
end
```

Mass assignment comes from passing the hash of POST parameters into the `new` or `create` action of a Rails controller. The values of the hash are then assigned to the user being created, e.g.:

```
def create
  # params[:user] contains { name: "Example", email: "..."}
  User.create(params[:user])
  #...
end
```

For the sake of security, `attr_accessible` has to be used to specify which fields are allowed to be mass-assigned. Otherwise, if the user had an `admin` flag, someone could just post `admin: true` as data to your app, and make themselves an admin.

#### In summary

`attr_accessor` is a helper method for Ruby classes, whereas `attr_accessible` is an ActiveRecord thing for rails, to tighten up security.

Comment: but my problem is when i create object i.e. user = User.new(params[:user]), it creates #<User:0xa82dd04 @attributes={}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=false> when user inherited from activeresource, if i access any of its attribuet i have to use user.attributes['name'] instead of user.name as it gives nil

Comment: You don't want to use `attr_accessor :name`, you want `attr_accessible :name`

Comment: no, i want to use attr_accessor.. but when i define :user_name instead of :name as attr_accessor then its working as i get usine User.name.. why is it so.?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have attr_accessor to work with ActiveResource. 
The base model (ActiveResource::Base) contains the @attributes hash in which you can 'dump' properties as you wish. (you should be careful though on what params you allow)

The way it does this, is by handling the method_missing? method. 
You can take a look [here](https://github.com/rails/activeresource/blob/master/lib/active_resource/base.rb#L1534)

If you define attr_accessor, what ruby does is that it creates a setter and a getter method, so it will break the method_missing functionality since it will never get to execute that code.

If you still want to use attr_accessor, you should create a Concern something like this:

module Attributes
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

```
  module ClassMethods
    def attr_accessor(*attribs)
      attribs.each do |a|

        define_method(a) do
          @attributes[a]
        end

        define_method("#{a}=") do |val|
          @attributes[a] = val
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```